# Edit image to make text more clear opencv

Tags: java, android, opencv

I'm developing an android app to recognize text in particular plate, as in photo here:
[plate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNbhQ.png)

I have to recognize the texts in white (e.g. near to "Mod."). All works fine but I have a "small" problem in some situations. Sometime the text differs due to light (or shadow) on plate when a photo is taken, e.g.:
[shadow plate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AX9qb.png)

Is there a way to make text more clear according to lights or shadows?
Thank you.

Comment: If you are using RGB color space, try using HSV or LAB. HSV is more more robust in case of changes in lighting conditions.

Comment: You can try brightness and contrast enhancements, it could help reduce noise from lighting effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [Gamma Correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction) on the v channel in HSV colorspace to lighter the dark image.

> (1) Convert to HSV, and split the H,S,V channel
>
> (2) Do gamma correction on the V channel
>
> (2) Merge and convert back to BGR

[image]

The source image, apply gamma=0.3 on the v channel in HSV. The corrected image looks like more clear:

[image]

More example:

[image]

Releated:

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction

Comment: Hi, thank you for reply. I use gamma correction already and it seems works. But my problem is that I don't know in what light conditions the photo is taken. I have to try to use gamma correction for a "general purpose".

Comment: If you want the process to be automatic, then try to calculate the gamma according to the V value distrubute?

Comment: Can I compute the mean of V value and set a threshold to choose right gamma value?

Comment: Yes. Maybe it's will be better if take consider of the mean, variance, and standard deviation of the V channel.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try use cvtColor COLOR_BGR2HSV" you get array [h][s][v]

H – Hue ( Dominant Wavelength ).
S – Saturation ( Purity / shades of the color ).
V – Value ( Intensity ).
edit value intensity max value is 255.

or try using the function ([find edge](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/canny_detector/canny_detector.html) or [conture](https://www.learnopencv.com/opencv-threshold-python-cpp/)) and then the result of recognizing the text